# How to get the button state in WinAPI?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to get the state of a button (enabled/disabled) using WinAPI in C#. I managed to get that specific button's hwnd using `FindWindowEx`, how could I proceeds from here? Sorry there's no snippet of code as I don't know where to begin. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the [`IsWindowEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646303(v=vs.85).aspx) function.